# Setting up DNS assistance

Tags: dns, redirection, wordpress

I want to make `example.com` and `www.example.com` point to `blog.example.com`. I cannot test this because DNS updates on live websites are so slow and I am not sure what record is not applying as it should.

My current setup is:

`example.com` site has two subdomains:
`www` and `blog`.

**example.com** has the following records:

1. `example.com SOA 'some default value from my provider'` (not quite sure what SOA record is)
2. `blog.example.com NS dns1.myprovider.com`
3. `blog.example.com NS dns2.myprovider.com`
4. `example.com NS dns1.myprovider.com`
5. `example.com NS dns2.myprovider.com`
6. `www.example.com NS dns1.myprovider.com`
7. `www.example.com NS dns2.myprovider.com`
8. `example.com TXT 'some default values from my provider'` (not quite sure what TXT record is)

'**www**' subdomain has the following records:

1. `SOA` record(default value)
2. `NS` record(dns1) (not removable)
3. `NS` record(dns2) (not removable)

'**blog**' subodmain has following records:

1. `SOA` record(default value)
2. `NS` record(dns1) (not removable)
3. `NS` record(dns2) (not removable)
4. `A` record(actual IP of server)

Beside this, I have defined **two redirects**:

`example.com` to `blog.example.com`

`www.example.com` to `blog.example.com`

Now when I go to `blog.example.com` it works as it should. When I go to `example.com` I am redirected to `www.example.com` and `www.example.com` returns "server DNS address could not be found."

What did I do wrong?

EDIT: Update after suggestions from Twisty. Current setup is:
https://pasteboard.co/bRfMKJv09.png

And now I don't have redirection from www.example.com to blog.example.com

Comment: What kind of redirects are we talking about here? CNAME records or something else?

Comment: By the way, hostnames like www.example.com and blog.example.com are usually handled with simple A records, not as full subdomains. Subdomains are for when you want to create another whole layer of names.

Comment: I dont know what kind of redirects I defined. I just have "Manage redirects" on my provider's domain control panel. I can remove those redirects if I manage to setup redirecton with records. How can I handle that redirects with A record? Is'n't A record used for allocating IP of server?

Comment: You can also look at using Hurricane Electric - https://dns.he.net to manage your DNS; They provide a free DNS service which is usually vastly more configurable than most ISP's. 
SOA record is "Start Of Authority" - The SOA record stores information about the name of the server that supplied the data for the DNS zone
A TXT record is often used for SPF mail records - Sender protection Framework

Comment: But looking at your question, I'd say that the reason 'blog.example.com' works is that as @Spiff has mentioned, it has an A record, which tells the querying DNS server where to point.  'www.example.com' has no 'A' record so any querying DNS server will not know what IP address to return.

Comment: @Dario Thank you for explanation. As for configuration: I am expecting that my DNS redirects www.example.com to blog.example.com before it looks for IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution to my problem was to create subdomain 'www'. After adding 'www' subdomain, my page is being redirected to 'blog.example.com' with rules 'manage redirections' that was available from my ISP's DNS control panel.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. However, something doesn't add up here. You stated in your original post that you already had a `www` subdomain, but it wasn't working. Did perhaps some of the changes made in my answer provide part of the solution?

Comment: I had 2 redirection rules at beginning and 2 subdomains, but redirection didn't work. Your answer is part of solution because I needed A record for example.com directing to blog server address.

Comment: One more thing was also important so that my dns redirects work. For 'www.example.com' A record should point to default IP that my ISP set, not to actual server  where my website is.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to accomplish this with DNS records:

1. Remove the `www` and `blog` subdomains. They're superfluous for what you're trying to accomplish.

Then, in the example.com domain:

2. Create an A record with the following values:
   **Host:** `@` (None)
   **Points to:**  `Actual IP of server`
3. Create an A record with the following values:
   **Host:** `blog`
   **Points to:**  `Actual IP of server`
4. Create a CNAME record with the following values:
   **Host:** `www`
   **Points to:**  `blog.example.com`

Now here's what happens when a visitor navigates to the various hostnames:

- For `blog.example.com` the A record points them to the server
- For `www.example.com` the CNAME record points them to blog.example.com
- For `example.com` the A record points them to the server

Your server-side redirect from example.com to blog.example.com is still necessary. However the redirect for www.example.com to blog.example.com should no longer be required (you can leave both in place to be safe though).

For the root domain (example.com) you might be tempted to use a CNAME record to point to blog.example.com, however CNAME'ing a root record is generally discouraged for reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/757972/2227908).

Comment: This is partially working. I removed both subodmains, Added 'blog.example.com A IP' record, added 'www.example.com CNAME blog.example.com', added 'example.com A IP'. I cannot type @ as Host value, also I cannot add 'example.com CNAME blog.example.com', but I added ISP's 'redirections' and now my example.com is not being redirected also I am not sure why I need A record for example.com if I have redirect defined for that url.

Comment: 1) Depending on your DNS provider's interface, you may just need to leave the host for the example.com A record blank to create the `@`. 2) As I said in my answer, you should not create a CNAME for the root example.com domain. The A record for the @ host will take care of lookups targeting the naked domain name. 3) The reason your example.com is not being "redirected" is because you don't have the A record for the @ host name. 4) The reason you need the A record for the root domain is because DNS lookups happen *before* redirects configured on your server. If there is no DNS record...

Comment: ...to capture traffic to example.com, the server redirect never gets a chance to work.

Comment: I did what you said. Take a look: https://pasteboard.co/bRfMKJv09.png But I am still not having redirect from www. to blog.

Comment: When you ping `www.example.com` does it return the IP address of the server?

Comment: Yes. Ping returns valid IP.

Comment: Then the problem is that your blog's server is seeing the header in the HTTP request for "www.example.com" and is not recognizing this as being intended for blog.example.com.  That needs to be fixed on the server.  Everything is correct in DNS.

Comment: Blog is Wordpress site with setting that default website url is blog.example.com. Anyhow, When I started with configuring DNS I had this redirection, but some other stuff didn't work and after I reset to default settings, I wasn't able to get that redirect back. P.S. Any link on www.example.com is pointing to blog.exampe.com. Do you have any resource for that needed server fix you are mentioning?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that on WordPress. You can ask on SE.Web Apps